# Second and subsequent Route in react-router-dom is not being rendered?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have been working with **react-router-dom** v4 and i am trying to make a central config for the routes with a workaround.

This is my routes.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import {
 WebsiteFilter,
 WebsiteLeaderBoard,
 WebsiteGraph,
 WebsiteQues
}
 from "./components";


import { DashboardApp ,LeaderBoardApp} from "./containers";
    
const dashboardContainer = (id) => (
 <DashboardApp key={id}>
  <Switch>
   <Route exact path="/dashboard" render={(props)  => (
   <>
    <WebsiteFilter />
    <WebsiteGraph />
    <WebsiteQues />
   </>
   )}
   />
  </Switch>

 </DashboardApp>
);

const leaderBoardContainer = (id) => (
 <LeaderBoardApp key={id}>
  <Switch>
   <Route exact path="/leaderboard" render={(props) => (
    <>
     <WebsiteLeaderBoard />
    </>
   )} />
  </Switch>
 </LeaderBoardApp>
);


const container =  [ dashboardContainer , leaderBoardContainer ];

const Routes = () => {
 return (
  <BrowserRouter baseName="/">
   <Switch>
    {container.map((pages,id) => (
     pages(id)
    ))}
   </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
 );
};

export default Routes;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This is my DashboardApp.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { WebsiteHeader ,  WebsiteFooter} from "../components";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import classes from "./app.scss";

class DashBoardApp extends Component {

 render() {
  return (
   <div className={classes.app}>
    <WebsiteHeader/>
     <>
      {this.props.children}
     </>
     <WebsiteFooter />
   </div>

  );
 }
}

export default DashBoardApp;

DashBoardApp.propTypes = {
 children :  PropTypes.element,
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This is my LeaderBoardApp.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { WebsiteHeader ,  WebsiteFooter} from "../components";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import classes from "./app.scss";

class LeaderBoardApp extends Component {

 render() {
  return (
   <div className={classes.app}>
    <WebsiteHeader/>
     <>
      {this.props.children}
     </>
     <WebsiteFooter />
   </div>
  
  );
 }
}

export default LeaderBoardApp;

LeaderBoardApp.propTypes = {
 children :  PropTypes.element,
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I have set my Link:

```
export default function HeaderLink (props) {
const { wrapperClass, dashboardClass } = props;
return (
    <ul className={wrapperClass}>
        <li className={[dashboardClass,classes.active].join(" ") }><Link to ="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link></li>
        <li className={dashboardClass}> <Link to ="/leaderboard">Leaderboard</Link></li>
    </ul>
);
```

}

According to this the link should work , but when i try to click the leaderboard link , it doesn't render the Websiteleaderboard component. But it always render the First route when i click the dashboard link as it's the first after switch statement. 
I searched online , and thought about it a lot , but couldn't found any solution. I don't know what's the problem here.

Here's the picture of rendered routes:
First pic

[image: DASHBOARD]

Second pic

[image: LEADERBOARD]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple `<Switch>` elements in what you're trying to do. From the docs:

> When a `<Switch>` is rendered, it will only render the first child  that matches the current location.

[Docs here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/migrating.md)

Removing all the switches except the wrapper should work. However, might I suggest a cleaner approach:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import {
    WebsiteFilter,
    WebsiteLeaderBoard,
    WebsiteGraph,
    WebsiteQues
}
    from "./components";


import { DashboardApp ,LeaderBoardApp} from "./containers";

const dashboardContainer = () => (
    <DashboardApp>
        <WebsiteFilter />
        <WebsiteGraph />
        <WebsiteQues />
    </DashboardApp>
);

const leaderBoardContainer = () => (
    <LeaderBoardApp>
        <WebsiteLeaderBoard />
    </LeaderBoardApp>
);


const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter baseName="/">
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/dashboard" component={dashboardContainer} />
                <Route path="/leaderboard" component={leaderBoardContainer} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
};

export default Routes;
```

By doing this, your entire configuration is contained in the `Routes`. You could even move the components out of that file, and have your `Routes` contained to only the actual routes, while importing the components you want to use.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked...OMG that's the  error